# Flask doesn't see the content of the database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect an already existing SQL database to my Flask app. It is already  defined with sqlite3 on python using this SQL command

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS qa (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    subject VARCHAR(500),
    question VARCHAR(500),
    correct_answer VARCHAR(500),
    choice_a VARCHAR(500),
    choice_b VARCHAR(500),
    choice_c VARCHAR(500),
    choice_d VARCHAR(500)
    );
```

It also contains 149481 rows

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('questions_and_answers.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT COUNT(*) FROM qa;""")
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

prints

```
[(149481,)]
```

However when I try to connect this database file to Flask and access rows, flask says there are 0 rows in this table. What am I doing wrong? The questions_and_answers.db is in the same directory as the code here.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import func, inspect
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///questions_and_answers.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True

db = SQLAlchemy(app)



class Question(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'qa'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    subject = db.Column(db.String(500))
    question = db.Column(db.String(500))
    correct_answer = db.Column(db.String(500))
    choice_a = db.Column(db.String(500))
    choice_b = db.Column(db.String(500))
    choice_c = db.Column(db.String(500))
    choice_d = db.Column(db.String(500))
    

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Question {self.id}>'

with app.app_context():
    db.reflect()
    db.create_all()
    results = Question.query.all()
    print(len(results))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Try using the full path to the database file, e.g., `'sqlite:////path/to/questions_and_answers.db'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that Flask was looking for the database file in the instance directory and it created a new empty one there since it couldn't find it there.